# How do I redirect non-www to www with .htaccess without URL-(re)encoding?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web, url-encoding

My problem in using any of the following code to redirect non-`WWW` to `WWW` is that the URL becomes encoded.

For example:

```
example.com/x%20y
```

Gets re-encoded (when redirected) to:

```
www.example.com/x%2520y
```

Which, according to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.4), is incorrect.  This behavior degrades mimetex output, among others.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How may I redirect to `WWW` with htaccess without re-encoding?

Comment: It's an answer, no joke - the correct one at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the flag `NE`, which stands for `no encoding`.

Like this `[R=301,NE,L]` and see if that helps keep in mind you will have to either use a different browser than what you're use to use or clear your cache since you're using 301 redirects and they might have been cached.

A full example would be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

I personally like using `%{REQUEST_URI}`.